# Strapi is not able to link authenticated user entry to its post

Tags: strapi

Hi I am evaluating straps to see if its relationships are working. So I am using StrapiCMS on my local Mac osx with MySQL as database.

I have created a collection called steps and it column
stepCount (int)
Date (Datetime)
User (User has man steps (relation))

So I have User collection and Step collection

expectation:

1. User should login using API POST api/auth/local (DONE)
2. Using token try to create entry to Steps POST api/steps (DONE)
3. Check entries on CMS (DONE)
4. NOW problem is I cannot see which user made the entry. I was hoping that strapi should have automatically created logged in user entry to the collection.

Now tell me what I need to do to get it working.

[image]

Comment: Th easiest would be to pass `user: {id}` inside your data object. Otherwise you have to mod controller or do middleware.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options here, with Post request pass user id:

```js
{
  data: {
    User: { 
      id: yourUser.id 
    },
    Date: ... ,
    stepCounts: ... ,
  }
}
```

otherwise you have to use controller, middleware or lifecycle, and append user in there, the lifecycle:

crete lifecycles js in:
`/src/api/step/content-types/step/lifecycles.js`

with following content:

```js
export default {
  beforeCreate(event) {
     const ctx = strapi.requestContext.get();
     const { user } = ctx.state;
     
     event.params.data.User = user; 
  }
}
```

this is going to work only for Authenticated REST calls, not for public or  admin.

Comment: Hi @antokhio do I have to make modification to Step collection model in Strapi to make this work? I tried to enter User object with id but it did not reflect in Step collection. User: { 
      id: 2
    }

Comment: {
    "data":{
        "user":{
            "id":2,
        },
    "stepCounts":101,
    "Date":"2023-04-20 17:00:00"
    }
}

Comment: Yes step collection should have hasOne relation to user